# How can I display large coordinates within the coordinatesystem?

Tags: java, swing, coordinate-transformation, affinetransform, wkt

I would like to plot some points from a given wkt file, but because of their closeness I only can display a heap of ovals that are overlapped.

The points differ only in their decimal places:

```
  POINT (3346349.958 5642197.806)
  POINT (3346349.313 5642199.622)
  POINT (3346349.237 5642201.918)
  POINT (3346349.734 5642204.058)
  POINT (3346351.746 5642205.777)
  POINT (3346351.636 5642210.304)
  POINT (3346349.335 5642216.518)
  POINT (3346347.326 5642221.15)
  POINT (3346347.365 5642223.671)
  POINT (3346351.577 5642195.711)
  etc...
```

First I tried to plot the points, but as I have mentioned all points are seemingly displayed at the same place.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException;

public class Display extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private WKTGrabsteine p = new WKTGrabsteine();

    public Display() {
        setLayout(null);
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.translate(height, width);

        try {
            for (int point = 0; point < p.geoCoordinates().size(); point++) {
                Ellipse2D shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(p.geoCoordinates().get(point).getX() / 1000000 + 400,
                        p.geoCoordinates().get(point).getY() / 1000000 + 100, 5, 5);

                g2.draw(shape);
            }

        } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

However I thought that the solution could lie in rescaling the coordinate system, which I tried to transform by Affinetransform and .scale()

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Graphics2D;
 import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
 import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
 import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
 import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
 import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException;

 public class Display extends JPanel {
 /**
 *
 */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private int width;
 private int height;
 private WKTGrabsteine p = new WKTGrabsteine();

 public Display() {
 setLayout(null);
 width = 0;
 height = 0;
 repaint();
 }

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
 super.paintComponent(g);
 setBackground(Color.WHITE);

 Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
 AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
 g2.translate(height, width);
 at.scale(6000000, 6000000);

 try {
 for (int point = 0; point < p.geoCoordinates().size(); point++) {
 Ellipse2D shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(p.geoCoordinates().get(point).getX(),
 p.geoCoordinates().get(point).getY(), 10, 10);

 g2.transform(at);
 g2.draw(shape);
 }

 } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 }



 }

 }
```

In fact I am quite new to this topic and have no clue how to make all points visible. Would be great if somebody could help me. 
Many thanks

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some example co=ordinates to remove the need fore the external file and 3rd party API. 2) `setLayout(null);` This is unnecessary when custom painting, detrimental otherwise.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson now it works perfectly thanks a lot for your help!
I will consider your hints in future posts

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of scaling and translating affine transforms.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class PointPlotter {

    Point2D.Double[] points = {
        new Point2D.Double(3346349.958, 5642197.806),
        new Point2D.Double(3346349.313, 5642199.622),
        new Point2D.Double(3346349.237, 5642201.918),
        new Point2D.Double(3346349.734, 5642204.058),
        new Point2D.Double(3346351.746, 5642205.777),
        new Point2D.Double(3346351.636, 5642210.304),
        new Point2D.Double(3346349.335, 5642216.518),
        new Point2D.Double(3346347.326, 5642221.15),
        new Point2D.Double(3346347.365, 5642223.671),
        new Point2D.Double(3346351.577, 5642195.711)
    };
    public static int SZ = 400;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(SZ, SZ, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    private JComponent ui = null;

    PointPlotter() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void drawImage() {
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, SZ, SZ);

        Area area = new Area();
        double r = 0.3;
        for (Point2D.Double point : points) {
            Ellipse2D.Double e = new Ellipse2D.Double(
                    point.getX() - r, point.getY() - r, 2*r, 2*r);
            area.add(new Area(e));
        }
        Rectangle2D rect = area.getBounds2D();
        double w = rect.getWidth();
        double h = rect.getHeight();
        double max = w>h ? w : h;
        double s = SZ/max;
        AffineTransform scale = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(s, s);
        double tX = -rect.getMinX();
        double tY = -rect.getMinY();
        AffineTransform translate = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(tX, tY);

        AffineTransform transform = scale;
        transform.concatenate(translate);

        area = new Area(transform.createTransformedShape(area));

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.draw(area);

        g.dispose();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }
        drawImage();

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        ui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                PointPlotter o = new PointPlotter();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```